# assert variable is threading._Event protected class instance

Tags: assert, python-2.x, python-multithreading

I want to check that a a variable `e` is an instance of `threading.Event`. However, when I create `e`, it actually creates a protected class instance `threading._Event`. For example:

```
import threading
e = threading.Event()
assert type(e) == threading.Event   # raises AssertionError
assert type(e) == threading._Event  # succeeds
```

Asserting that it is a protected class instance seems un-pythonic. Would `assert type(e) == type(threading.Event())` be better? Would another option be better yet?

Comment: `threading.Event` is not a class. The documentation describes it as a factory function.

Comment: ...oh goddammit, this is another case of conflicting documentation. Some parts of the docs actually do call it a class. At least the 3.3+ docs are correct (since it actually became a class at that point).

Comment: If you want to perform an explicit type check, I'd use `type(threading.Event())` and save that to a variable.

Comment: `assert type(e) == threading.Event` works in Python 3 but `assert type(e) == threading._Event` doesn't (`_Event` not recognized)

Comment: @user2357112 Why save it to a variable instead of just use it and delete it as in my example?

Comment: @ericksonla: To avoid creating tons of event objects. I don't know how heavyweight those are, and future readers of the code likely won't know either.

Comment: @user2357112 Why won't it be deleted immediately after the line its created?

Comment: @ericksonla: The worry isn't that the event objects will stick around and hog resources; the worry is that the act of creating them might be expensive.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look [at this answer about subclassing `threading.Event`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17998861/1388292).

> threading.Event is not a class, it's function in threading.py
>
> `def Event(*args, **kwargs):
>       """A factory function that returns a new event.
>       Events manage a flag that can be set to true with the set() method and reset
>       to false with the clear() method. The wait() method blocks until the flag is
>       true.
>       """
>       return _Event(*args, **kwargs)`
>
> Since this function returns _Event instance, you can subclass _Event (although it's never a good idea to import and use underscored names):
>
> `from threading import _Event
>   class State(_Event):
>       def __init__(self, name):
>           super(Event, self).__init__()
>           self.name = name
>       def __repr__(self):
>           return self.name + ' / ' + self.is_set()`

This was changed in Python 3:

> `class Event:
>       """Class implementing event objects.
>       Events manage a flag that can be set to true with the set() method and reset
>       to false with the clear() method. The wait() method blocks until the flag is
>       true.  The flag is initially false.
>       """`